# Transform Quaternion

Tags: quaternion, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

Is there a package witch transforms the quaternion coordinates automatically in an other system? (Axis-Angle, Kardan, Euler)

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50113/transform-quaternion/) by [JaRu](https://answers.ros.org/users/3620/jaru/) on ROS Answers with karma: 153 on 2012-12-10

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The tf::Quaternion class is (currently) built on top of the Bullet quaternion class - here's an [overview](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf/Overview/Data%20Types).

You have all the methods available in [btQuaternion](http://bulletphysics.com/Bullet/BulletFull/classbtQuaternion.html). You can also create a [btMatrix3x3](http://bulletphysics.com/Bullet/BulletFull/classbtMatrix3x3.html) from the btQuaternion and use any of the class methods.

After a quick scan, I'm seeing

- `getAngle()`
- `getAxis()`
- `getEulerYPR(..)`
- `getEulerZYX(..)`

**EDIT**: as per narcispr's comment:

Let's say `q` is your quaternion. This is what I usually do (there might be a more elegant way, but I haven't found it)

```
tf::Matrix3x3 m(q);
double roll, pitch, yaw;
m.getRPY(roll, pitch, yaw);
```

---

Originally posted by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) with karma: 4954 on 2012-12-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 23

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [narcispr](https://answers.ros.org/users/1214/narcispr/) on 2013-02-07**:
I was also looking for some way to transform from quaternion to euler in C++. Can you post a code snippet please?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just to complete the previous response:

```
#include <tf/transform_datatypes.h>
// ...
tf::Quaternion q(quat.x, quat.y, quat.z, quat.w);
tf::Matrix3x3 m(q);
double roll, pitch, yaw;
m.getRPY(roll, pitch, yaw);
std::cout << "Roll: " << roll << ", Pitch: " << pitch << ", Yaw: " << yaw << std::endl;
```

Where *quat* contains the quaternion values to be transformed to roll, pitch, yaw.

---

Originally posted by [narcispr](https://answers.ros.org/users/1214/narcispr/) with karma: 307 on 2013-02-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 15

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems that creating a Matrix3X3 from the quaternion is not necessary since a transform already contains the rotation matrix. If you are working with TF, inside every Quaternion there is a Matrix3x3 called m_basis. When you call Transform::getRotation(), what you get is

From http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/tf/html/c++/Transform_8h_source.html :

```
00120         Quaternion getRotation() const { 

00121                 Quaternion q;

00122                 m_basis.getRotation(q);

00123                 return q;

00124         }
```

So it could be that you may get away with:

```
transform.getBasis().getRPY(roll, pitch, yaw);
```

---

Originally posted by [PedroGusmao](https://answers.ros.org/users/7556/pedrogusmao/) with karma: 66 on 2014-10-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) on 2014-10-16**:
If you have a transform object, yes. The original question asks how to do this with get rotation from a quaternion object.